# XSLT 1.0: element template only allowed as child of stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am attempting to compile an XSLT 1.0 stylesheets and am getting this error:

```
#<RuntimeError: compilation error: element template
element template only allowed as child of stylesheet
```

The error seems like an obvious fix, but there's no indication in my stylesheet markup that any `template` element's are using are not a `child of stylesheet`. Below is my entire template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/message">
  {
    "heading": "<xsl:apply-templates select="normalize-space(heading/text())"/>",
    "note_id": <xsl:apply-templates select="number(NoteID)"/>,
    "player_id": <xsl:apply-templates select="number(PlayerID)"/>,
    "team_id": <xsl:apply-templates select="number(TeamID)"/>,
    "first_name": "<xsl:apply-templates select="normalize-space(Firstname/text())"/>",
    "last_name": "<xsl:apply-templates select="normalize-space(Lastname/text())"/>",
    "position": "<xsl:apply-templates select="normalize-space(Position/text())"/>",
    "hot_cold": "<xsl:apply-templates select="normalize-space(HotCold/text())"/>",
    "status": "<xsl:apply-templates select="normalize-space(Status/text())"/>",
    "description": "<xsl:apply-templates select="Description/*"/>",
    "insight": "<xsl:apply-templates select="Insight/*"/>",
    "timestamp": "<xsl:apply-templates select="time_stamp/*">"
  }

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="escaped-text">
      <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&quot;'" />
          <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'\&quot;'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($escaped-text)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replace-string">
      <xsl:param name="text"/>
      <xsl:param name="replace"/>
      <xsl:param name="with"/>
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
              <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                  <xsl:with-param name="text"
                      select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the apply-templates tag isn't closed properly:
improper:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="time_stamp/*">
```

proper:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="time_stamp/*"/>
```